# How to Best Setup an Escrow Wallet/Account in NEAR Protocol?

Tags: rust, blockchain, cryptocurrency, nearprotocol

Objective: We are building a dual flow system on NEAR. The flow is something like:
*Client -> Escrow Wallet -----true---> Beneficiary

Client -> Escrow Wallet -----false--> Client*

I was just wondering if there is a standard procedure for this. Because hard-coding a wallet address to act as the escrow wallet does not sound very reasonable or safe. So please let me know, what might be a better way to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Suppose some client has to pay an artist 10 NEAR, but only if the artist completes a task. So, on creation of task, the NEAR flow from the client wallet to the escrow wallet. And if the task is done successfully, the NEAR should move to the artist's wallet, else they should go back to the client wallet. That's the intended functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your desired custodian/escrow behavior in a `smart contract`'s logic. I'm not sure what you mean by hard-coding an account, but this escrow contract's logic would remain unchanged once you have deployed it to the network, as such, you can rely on it as much as you can rely on the network for your application's logic.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.

One is creating an a wallet for the specific scrow service and then erasing it at the end of the transaction.

function one - Bob ask for an scrow service, the contract is deployed and tokens sent in same transaction

function two - Alice sent the other part, the contract send tokens from Bob to Alice and from Alice to Bob, closes the contract and send remaining funds to master contract

---

The Second and easier:

function one - send 5 N from Bob to the Smart contract address

function two - accept from Alice AND in the same function send the another part

Of course this needs more logic and information from your question, an a task maybe is something that couldn´t be sent in the blockchain, so it always will require honesty from one part.